# SQL Door access

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm pretty new to sql and have been set a task of creating a query which will give me the first and last entrance of each user and how long they were in the office for.
So far i have got the below

```
SELECT 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),evts.Eventtime,101) as Date,
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),evts.Eventtime,108) as Time,
un.UserName AS [User], 
case 
when p.Name = 'ACU:4321104 - 5th floor (In)' then '5th entrance'
when p.name = 'ACU:4321176 - 4th floor (In)' then '4th entrance'
when p.name = 'ACU:4321176 - 4th floor (Out)' then '4th exit'
when p.name = 'ACU:4321104 - 5th floor (Out)' then '5th exit'
when p.name = 'ACU:4321158 - 3rd Floor (In)' then '3rd entrance'
when p.name = 'ACU:4321158 - 3rd Floor (Out)' then '3rd exit'
end as [where]
FROM                    
Net2Events.dbo.Events AS evts LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.vw_UserNamesFS AS un ON evts.UserID = un.UserID LEFT OUTER JOIN
Net2Events.dbo.[Event subtype description] AS esd ON evts.EventSubType = esd.EventSubType LEFT OUTER JOIN
Net2Events.dbo.[Event description] AS ed ON evts.EventType = ed.EventType LEFT OUTER JOIN
dbo.Peripherals AS p ON evts.Address = p.Address AND evts.SubAddr = p.SubAddr
    WHERE evts.EventTime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
        AND evts.EventTime < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Which gives access to every entrance and exit. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The code looks like SQL Server, not MS Access.

Comment: Looks like you need to do a select min(), max() group by user.

Comment: Hi Carra, Select min what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will almost certainly need to adjust your `where` clause if this is more than a one off report, but for all `EventTime`s between those two dates, this query will give you the first and last `EventTime` by each user and the time between those in minutes.

If you need to further break this down by specific flors, you can add your `where` field back in (Though I would recommend against that name, as it is a SQL keyword) to both the `select` and the `group by`:

```
SELECT un.UserName AS [User]
    ,MIN(evts.Eventtime) as FirstEvent
    ,MAX(evts.Eventtime) as LastEvent
    ,DATEDIFF(minute,MIN(evts.Eventtime),MAX(evts.Eventtime)) as TimeDifference

FROM Net2Events.dbo.Events AS evts
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vw_UserNamesFS AS un
        ON evts.UserID = un.UserID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Net2Events.dbo.[Event subtype description] AS esd
        ON evts.EventSubType = esd.EventSubType
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Net2Events.dbo.[Event description] AS ed
        ON evts.EventType = ed.EventType
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Peripherals AS p
        ON evts.Address = p.Address
            AND evts.SubAddr = p.SubAddr

WHERE evts.EventTime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND evts.EventTime < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0)

GROUP BY un.UserName
```

I think you will need to do more than just the first and last event however, as I don't think there is a production database in the world with 100% correct data.  This means you will need to find the earliest `In` event and the latest `Out` event and then check that these make sense.

You can 'exclude' certain rows from aggregates like `min` and `max` with a case statement that substitutes an impossible value way beyond the normal range which you can handle if needs be later on:
`min(case when <criteria to include> then EventTime else '29990101' end)`

---

## Edit to add in response to comment

To format your Time Difference into various date elements, you need to start with your largest date part - ie: Days?  Hours? - and then work down from there.  Start with working out how many full days you have, which for a value in minutes means doing integer division by 60 to get the number of full hours and then by 24 to get the number of full days:

```
@difference / 60 / 24
```

We then need the number of full hours, minus all the hours taken up in the full days.  To do this we can do the above calculation by use `modulo` instead of `division` to find the remainder of the hours that don't create a full day:

```
@difference / 60 % 24
```

And then to find the number of minutes left over, we simply need to find the remainder of a division by 60:

```
@difference % 60
```

Do some `cast/convert`ing to get the right formatting and you have your difference in Days, Hours and Minutes:

```
declare @start datetime = getdate() - 400.255;
declare @end datetime = getdate();

declare @difference int = datediff(minute,@start,@end);

select cast(@difference/60/24 as nvarchar(5)) + case when @difference/60/24 = 1 then ' Day, ' else ' Days, ' end
        + cast(@difference/60%24 as nvarchar(5)) + case when @difference/60%24 = 1 then ' Hour, ' else ' Hours, ' end
        + cast(@difference%60 as nvarchar(5)) + case when @difference%60 = 1 then ' Minute' else ' Minutes' end;
```

which returns: `400 Days, 6 Hours, 7 Minutes`

Of course, if you only ever want Hours and Minutes in `hh:mm` format and are super confident this time difference will never go over 23 hours, 59 minutes and 59.9999999 seconds, you can simply convert the difference to a time value by adding it to an arbitrary date, and formatting accordingly in your front end application:

```
cast(dateadd(minute,@difference,0) as time)
```

Which returns: `06:07:00.0000000` for the parameters above - Note the missing 400 days.

Comment: is it possible to convert the minutes into hours and minutes?

Comment: @BJAS  I have edited my answer to show you how you can do this.